# Module ValidatedNumerics error

Tags: julia

I am trying to use Julia for some computer assisted proof I want to do. So I installed it (in debian with apt-get) then I installed ValidatedNumerics with its package manager.

Then when I write

```
using ValidatedNumerics
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: ⊆ not defined
in include at boot.jl:238
at /home/user/.julia/v0.2/ValidatedNumerics/src/ValidatedNumerics.jl:5
```

I looked at the file and it tries to import from Base ⊆ among other things and apparently it fails. When I comment out ⊆, then the command does not return an error but unsurprisingly the module is broken and unusable.

What is this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: version 0.2? A bit old, perhaps.

Comment: Hi, ValidatedNumerics.jl author here. I'm very happy that you would like to use  the package. Please feel free to write issues on the repository or send me an email for any questions.  In this case @daycaster is right that your Julia version is far too old (2 years old?) The latest version of ValidatedNumerics.jl needs Julia v0.4. You can download this straight from the Julia homepage.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answering. I actually thought of trying it out after your talk last week at Warwick. It seems that the problem is that debian has an older version of Julia in its repositories. I will try to install the new version.

Comment: The problem was the old version in repos. I used the official repos for julia language and everything works fine. Kind of obvious I must admit.

Comment: What is not obvious is why the repositories still contain an ancient version.